# ORACLE Query doesnt work with insert statement

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have a question regarding this statement. its showing an error like this

```
Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00984: column not allowed here in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesInformationCenter\Component_request\save.php on line 41
```

and my code is like this,

```
 $componentHistoryParse = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO HISTORY_COMPONENT_CUTTING 
                    (BASE_PLATE, REQUESTER, REQUEST_DATE, QTY_PROPOSED, REMARKS, PROJECT_NAME, THICKNESS, REQ_STATUS)
             VALUES (:bp, $username, SYSDATE, :qt ,:rm , :pj, :tc, 'PENDING')");

oci_bind_by_name($componentHistoryParse, ":bp", $_POST['baseplate']);
oci_bind_by_name($componentHistoryParse, ":qt", $_POST['quantityToCut']);
oci_bind_by_name($componentHistoryParse, ":rm", $_POST['text_remarks']);
oci_bind_by_name($componentHistoryParse, ":pj", $_POST['projectName']);
oci_bind_by_name($componentHistoryParse, ":tc", $_POST['thickness']);

$componentHistoryRes = oci_execute($componentHistoryParse);

if($componentHistoryRes){
   oci_commit($conn);
} else {
   oci_rollback($conn);
}
```

and the column names in the table are

BASE_PLATE VARCHAR2, 
NAME VARCHAR2, 
REQUESTER VARCHAR2, 
REQUEST_DATE DATE, 
REMARKS VARCHAR2, 
PROJECT_NAME VARCHAR2, 
PROJECT_NO VARCHAR2, 
THICKNESS NUMBER, 
REQ_STATUS VARCHAR2, 
QTY_PROPOSED NUMBER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 $componentHistoryParse = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO HISTORY_COMPONENT_CUTTING 
                (BASE_PLATE, REQUESTER, REQUEST_DATE, QTY_PROPOSED, REMARKS, PROJECT_NAME, THICKNESS, REQ_STATUS)
         VALUES (:bp, '$username', SYSDATE, :qt ,:rm , :pj, :tc, 'PENDING')");
```

i.e. quotes around `$username`

Answer (score 1):

`$username` expands to just the value without any quotes, which then the database sees as a column name, not a string.

You could fix it by quoting username as `'$username'` but - better to avoid SQL injection - you should really put username in a parameter as you do the other values.